# Is there an analytic bounded function on $\omega \subset \mathbb C\setminus]-\infty;0]$ such that $|f(x)|\leq e^{-x^{1/2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there an analytic and bounded function on $\Omega \subset \mathbb C\setminus]-\infty;0]$ such that $|f(x)|\leq e^{-x^{1/2}}$; $x\geq 0$ ?

Comment: Trivially, there is $f\equiv 0$. Non-trivially, do you know what $\lvert e^w\rvert$ is? And can you see a connection between $\mathbb{C}\setminus ]-\infty,0]$ and $\sqrt{z}$?

Comment: Ok, there is the null function! $|e^{w}|=e^{x}$ with $w=x+iy$. I also know that $\sqrt z$ is well-defined on $\mathbb C ∖setminus ]−∞,0] $...So my analytic function is $z \rightarrow \sqrt z$ by analytic continuation?

Comment: Not $\sqrt{z}$, since $\sqrt{x} > e^{-x^{1/2}}$ for $x \geqslant 1$. But using $\sqrt{z}$, you can construct nonzero analytic functions satisfying the desired inequality.

Comment: ok Daniel. But i do not know how to construct such a function. Furthermore, my course is upon Jensen's formula and Phragmen-lindelof theorems (lecture on entire function by Levin). How can we use them in that case? I am still working on it. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: What about $e^{-\sqrt{z}}$ with the principal value of the square root? There are more you can construct in a similar way.

Comment: It seems to easy! The one you proposed is bounded by 1 on $\Omega$ and it coincides with $e^{-x^{1/2}}$ on the real line. We finally use the analytic continuation principle.Am i right?

Comment: Daniel i think i have to prove that "your" function is bounded (by 1) in an unbounded domain (here $\Omega$) so that's the point in the Phragmen-Lindelov's theorem.